# tkinter: LabelFrame in a separate TopLevel window

Tags: python, tkinter

My "simple" intention is to create a Dialog - launched by a button - where I have several `LabelFrames` with their radio button.

I tried with 1 `LabelFrame` with this simple code the radios appear in the main window, not in the dialogue one !!!! I cannot understand why. Please help.. ty for your attention

Here's the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class PersonEmptyDocsDialog(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root,personid):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.personid = personid
        self.code = tk.StringVar()

        frame1 = ttk.Labelframe(self,text='testo').grid(column=0,row=0,padx=20,pady=20)
        ttk.Radiobutton(frame1, text="Option 1", variable=self.code, value="0-0-0").pack()
        ttk.Radiobutton(frame1, text="Option 1", variable=self.code, value="0-0-1").pack()
        ttk.Radiobutton(frame1, text="Option 1", variable=self.code, value="0-0-2").pack()

        self.ok_button = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.on_ok).grid(column=0,row=1)

        #self.ok_button.pack()

    def on_ok(self, event=None):
        self.destroy()

    def show(self):
        self.wm_deiconify()
        self.wait_window()
        return self.code.get()

class Example():
    def __init__(self, root):
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.root = root
        ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Get Input", command=self.on_button).pack(padx=8, pady=8)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="", width=20).pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

    def on_button(self):
        string = PersonEmptyDocsDialog(self.root, 12).show()
        print(string)



root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("400x200")
Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put in one line. You need to break this into in line 11

```
frame1 = ttk.Labelframe(self,text='testo')
frame1.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=20,pady=20)
```

Output:

[image]

Output after clicking Get input button:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved by mentioning *why*. For example: "You cannot put it in one line because the `grid` method does not return a value."